# junit 4 testcases and test suites in the same folder

Tags: eclipse, unit-testing, junit4, testcase

I have some JUnit 4 test cases and test suites that are in the same directory. When I run these from eclipse using a right-click on the top level test directory, the all of the test cases that do not occur in a test suite get run, and all of the test suites get run but the test cases are green but do not look like they have been run in eclipse.

Normally i would prefer that the test suites *not* get run and just have the test cases run. Is there a way to do that? Should I put then in a different tree structure?

Also is there a way to make a test suite and just specify some tests methods instead of the entire class?

Answer (score 0):

In **Run -> Run Configuration** you can select your Junit Configuration.
From this menu you can launch the entire TestSuite or even a single method:

[Run Configuration Dialog](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xbHcZ.png)